# Facebook share extension crashing in iOS 11

Tags: facebook, uikit, ios11, ios8-share-extension

I'm using the `UIActivityViewController` to enable the user to share images on social media. However, Facebook's share dialog crashes in iOS 11 after a few seconds with the following log:

`[core] SLRemoteComposeViewController: (this may be harmless) viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={Terminated=disconnect method}
[core] SLComposeViewController remoteViewController: <SLRemoteComposeViewController: 0x1040b7e00> didTerminateWithError: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={Terminated=disconnect method}`

The error doesn't occur in iOS 10, though the image takes a few seconds to be displayed.

Any idea what's causing this issue? Do I have to wait for Facebook to fix this?

Comment: Yes, Facebook messager has it too. For some images works a workaround as using UIImage for activityItems instead of URLs. But it doesn't work for all images, I see that a lot of .jpg files fail to share. Will share more info when find out a reason for this.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook is no longer integrated in iOS 11. You can integrate the native Facebook SDK and use this code:

```
FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
photo.image = _image;
photo.userGenerated = YES;
FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
content.photos = @[photo];
[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:self];
```

It works only if the native Facebook app is installed on device(iOS 10 and prior without app) and you can check it:

```
BOOL isInstalledFBApp = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fbshareextension://"]];
```

For more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios/

Comment: It doesn't work on ios 11. I get `sharerDidCancel` callback.

Comment: It works ONLY IF the native Facebook app is installed on device, if not installed, you will get sharerDidCancel callback.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Karen Hovhannisyan is correct. Images with a scale larger than 1.0 will crash both Twitter and Facebook. Scaling the image does the trick. However its not really ideal.
I tried to normalise the image by increasing the size to match the resolution, but that also caused a crash. Might be because the image was too large.

```
func shareableImage(image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else { return image }
      let size: CGSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(cgImage.width) / image.scale, height: CGFloat(cgImage.height) / image.scale)

    defer {
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 1)

    image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))

    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() ?? image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue upon sharing images to Whatsapp where the share dialog closes by itself after a few seconds.
Thanks to @Mike Demidov, I realised that something is wrong with the images to be shared due to the way I saved the images as shown below.

```
if let testImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.testImageView.image!, 0.5) {

    let destinationUrl = DocumentHelper.getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(identifier + "_test.png")

    try? testImage.write(to: destinationUrl)

}
```

The reason being is because I'm using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` to convert the image but I was setting the image name / file format as .png.

All I did to solve my issue was to change it to .jpeg as shown below.

```
if let testImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.testImageView.image!, 0.5) {

    let destinationUrl = DocumentHelper.getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(identifier + "_test.jpeg")

    try? testImage.write(to: destinationUrl)

}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In may case Facebook, Twitter and Whatsapp share extensions crashing because share image scale property is > 1.0